# Persistent error with phpmyadmin "Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported"

Tags: apache2, mysql, php, phpmyadmin

The following error is in my `/var/log/apache2/error.log` file. I can not access the `index.php` file or any other phpmyadmin file, in replace of phpmyadmins interface my server returns an http 500 error. All other files work fine, its only phpmyadmin's which has this issue.

```
Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported in /usr/share/$
$share/phpmyadmin/libraries/Util.php on line 2087
```

I have tried reinstalling phpmyadmin and php but the issue persists. 
PHP version: 8.0.12 
phpmyadmin version: 4.6.6-5

Comment: Is anything not working in phpMyAdmin, or is it just a log message?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that when I try to visit the index file the server returns an error 500. Any other file works fine, including those of php type. Just phpmyadmin's is returning http 500.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you what the issue is:

`Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported in /usr/share/$ $share/phpmyadmin/libraries/Util.php on line 2087`

There are `{}` curly braces that are no longer supported in PHP.
here's a source to check out regarding this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/59158847#59158847

`sudo vi /share/phpmyadmin/libraries/Util.php`

go to line 2087

then edit the `{}` curly braces and replace them with `[]`

then type `:wq`

You can use any file editor you wish to, I personally use vim.

Since the above caused more issues do the following:

Run `sudo apt remove --purge phpmyadmin`
Then `sudo apt autoremove`

Then download the zip file from https://www.phpmyadmin.net/

The default location for the zip file should be `Downloads` unless you changed it

Next unzip the file, You can do this through the GUI into the default location which is `/`

Don't worry about changing it just unzip or `extract` right from there.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131408/discussion-on-answer-by-t-br-persistent-error-with-phpmyadmin-array-and-string).

Comment: In attempting to fix the original error a new error occured here's the error from the apache log: `[core:notice] [pid 19402] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2' [core:error] [pid 19423] [client 192.168.1.3:1035] AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/html/phpmyadmin'` The file `/var/www/html/phpmyadmin` doesn't exist and I don't know how to resolve this error.  I advised the OP to ask a new question during chat and link this log output, the version of PHP version: 8.0.12, the updated version of myphpadmin 5.1.1 and the ubuntu version.

Comment: Just for visibility, posting a direct quote from the OP "Finbar - Not entirely sure on how I fixed it but it seems to be working again. Thanks for all the help."